# Symfony 3.4 Where to Put Auto-Generating Proxy Class Config Mode?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Symfony is complaining about renaming proxy classes during my multiple instance command execution. Basically, I am running a Symfony command mutliple times at the same time, and it is throwing an error for generated proxy classes not being able to be renamed...

```
In ProxyGenerator.php line 293:
Warning: rename(/Users/jlroberts/Projects/Shred/Symfony/var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppBundleEntityNslocaleCountryNames.php.5ee27c106fc5f0.51071995,/Users/jlroberts/Projects/Shred/Symfony/var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppBundleEntityNslocaleCountryNames.php): No such file or directory
```

I found this issue on github

https://github.com/doctrine/common/issues/327

And I think it says to set the AutoGeneratedProxyClasses to AUTOGENERATE_FILE_NOT_EXISTS, which I found on

```
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html
```

Which says I use this following line to set that mode

```
$mode = AUTOGENERATE_FILE_NOT_EXISTS;
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($mode);
```

but where do I put that line?

Comment: why do you run the same command simultaneously?

Comment: So it runs Faster, The more concurrent executions I have, the faster it runs, network requests to the database and web api slow it down

Comment: I thought that's what threads are for. I'm *guessing* the error comes from a race condition, one process opening the file for writing, another trying to rename it or something. have you tried running your process once as a single process and then as multiple? does that change anything?

Comment: Single process it doesnt happen on, its a known issue, they say you can use eval too, but I dont know where to put that code, and I think that code, generates a yml entry in config.yml, any ideas on how to get that entry for config.yml? I think that line goes in Setup.php